# How can I add a seperate action listener to all 14 of my buttons at once that can determine player turn?(java)

Tags: java

I have a huge code, for a game I'm making called Togiz Kumalak. I know it's not pretty, but I'm very inexperienced and for some reason using arrays confounds me. Anyway, my problem is that I can't add to a variable outside of the listener and the modify the variable(pTurn++) from within the action listener.

How do I go about adding a count to that variable from inside the action listener?

1 error found:
File: C:\Users\Public\Togiz_Kumalak.java  [line: 130]
Error: local variable pTurn is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

```
int pTurn = 0;

button1.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pTurn++;
                if (pTurn % 2 == 0) {
                    display.append("\n Player 2 Cup 1");
                }
                if (pTurn % 2 != 0) {
                    display.append("\n Player 1 Cup 1")
                }
            }

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, move the contents of the actionPerformed method to the class and then invoke that method from within actionPerformed. For example:

```
private void buttonPressed {
    pTurn++;
    if(pTurn % 2 == 0) {
        display.append("\n Player 2 Cup 1");
    }
    if(pTurn % 2 !=0) {
        display.append("\n Player 1 Cup 1")}
    }
}
```

Then in your actionPerformed method:

```
button1.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            OuterClass.this.buttonPressed();
        }
    }
);
```

Where `OuterClass` is the name of your class.

Answer (score 0):

make pTurn a member

if you make it final, you will get an error for trying to change a final variable.

EDIT:
explanation

there are several types of variables

1. members ->they are defined in the scope of a class, they are available to every method in the given class
   , if made public they are available to anyone who uses this class.
2. local variables -> they are defined in the scope of a method, they are available only from within that method.

example

```
public class MyClass{

public Button b1; //<-member;
public int pTurn;//<-member;
public Label display;<-member;
public ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener(){//<- also member! you can define them like this as well.

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pTurn++;
                if (pTurn % 2 == 0) {
                    display.append("\n Player 2 Cup 1");
                }
                if (pTurn % 2 != 0) {
                    display.append("\n Player 1 Cup 1")
                }
            }


}

public boolean addActionListener(Button b){

b.addActionListener(actionListener);//<-- b is transfered by reference. meaning if you do addActionListener(button1) somewhere, it will work

boolean added = true ;//<- local variable, available only from within this method

return added;
}

}
```

should you do anywhere MyClass c = new MyClass();
you would have c.pTurn, c.display , c.actionListener, and c.b1 available for use.

make note though, you cannot use c.display and c.b1 unless they've been initialized first.
initialized means somevariable = new Something...

Comment: I'm not even sure what a member is. I'll look that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner class instead of anonymous class which you used -

```
private class MyListener implements ... {...}
```

and then

```
button1.addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

or use the advice of the compiler and set the variable to be final.